# Where does a SmartEyeglass app actually run?

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

I am currently trying to figure out what a SmartEyeglass really is and where it runs.

If I understood the documentation correctly, a SmartEyeglass app is always packaged as an Android application. That's why it consists of an Android manifest and an Activity. Sony provides the SmartEyeglass API to access the sensor data, handling events and define the SmartEyeglass specific user interface in the form of a control extension. A SmartEyeglass app is not a set of activities like a normal Android application. Instead it is bootstrapped using a Broadcast receiver and a service which starts the control extension.

A broadcast receiver registers on SmartEyeglass events and triggers the SmartEyeglass App service. The service starts the SmartEyeglass App.

Where does the SmartEyeglass run? Does it run on the SmartEyeglass or is it executed on the Android smartphone? It seems like it runs on the Android smartphone and sends remote commands to the SmartEyeglass over Bluetooth. On the SmartEyeglass run a customized Android and a Content Provider to access sensor and event data. Is that right?

What kind of role play the SmartEyeglass Android app and the SmartConnect app in the communication between the Android smartphone and the SmartEyeglass?
If I understood correctly the SmartEyeglass Android app is like a proxy to the SmartConnect App on the same device. The SmartConnect App communicates with the SmartEyeglass.

It would be nice to know what happens when I press the Swipe button within a SmartEyeglass application. I think:

1. The SmartEyeglass registers the event and sends the event to the SmartConnect app on the Android device
2. The SmartEyeglass app on the Android device is informed about the triggered event. It finds out which SmartEyeglass App fired the event and sends the event to it.
3. The event can now be handled within the app by implementing SmartEyeglassEventListener.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Sony SmartEyeglass run on the Android Host Device. That's why you can't run any SmartEyeglass app without a paired Android smartphone.